# How to check the position of an index.values in a pandas.core.series.Series

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am currently using pandas in my codes, but this is the first time that I am using **pandas.core.series.Series**

Version : Python 3.6.3

Despite browsing Stack Overflow and others, I did not find the answer to my question.

Here is my code:

```py
zz = df['dataframe column_name'].value_counts(sort = True)
```

Typing zz on the console gives:

```
In [11]: zz
Out[11]: 
FE    6            (Position 0)
PH    1            (Position 1)
DC    1            (Position 2)
SN    1            (Position 3)
Name: T, dtype: int64
```

I can check in a if clause, if a value "**FE**" exists:

```py
if zz.index.values[zl] == 'FE': #(where [zl] is the loop indice)
```

But I do not know how to retrieve the position of value "FE" (in this case position is 0)

I would like to add that "zz" is dynamic and in my code "zz" can be resized from 1 to 4 items, up to 5000 times in one run.

Thank you really for your time and your help :)

Comment: Maybe `numpy.argwhere`...? eg. `np.argwhere(zz.index == 'FE').flatten()[0]`

Comment: Thank you to Sparky05 who helped me formatting :)

Comment: I did not investigate about numpy, which I don't really know (or use) yet.   Thank you Chris A , this is exactly what I was looking for :) Have a nice day !